# finding last entry of foreach() loop, implode not working

Tags: php, foreach, implode

I loop through my array to print the articles names:

```
<?php
if ($articles) { 
    foreach($articles as $article) { 
        echo $article->name.", ";       
    } // end foreach article
} // end if has articles
?>
```

This will obviously produce something like

```
Apple, Banana, Mango,
```

But I am looking for:

```
Apple, Banana, Mango
```

I tried some implode statement like this:

```
<?php
if ($articles) { 
    foreach($articles as $article) { 
        echo implode(", ", $article->name);     
    } // end foreach article
} // end if has articles
?>
```

or

```
<?php
if ($articles) { 
    echo implode(", ", $articles->article->name);       
} // end if has articles
?>
```

None of these are working for me. How can do it right? Thanks for hints!

Comment: You have 2 choices: 1. do not use OOP syntax where it unnecessary. Use array where you need array and then take advantage of implode(). 2. find last entry. There are nearly dozen of methods. try to find at least one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `foreach` to add the article names to an array, then `implode()` that array of names.

```
<?php
if ($articles) { 
    $article_names = array();

    foreach($articles as $article) { 
        $article_names[] = $article->name;
    } // end foreach article

    echo implode(', ', $article_names);
} // end if has articles
?>
```

Comment: it looks ugly. 2 loops where only 1 needed.

Comment: @Col I can see only one loop.

Comment: @sexyprout: He's probably referring to the internal loop within `implode()`. (I haven't seen the source code for that function so I'm not sure if it's implemented with a loop.)

Comment: @sexyprout if you wrap this code into function, you won't see even one. It doesn't mean that this function doing it's job with magic wand.

Answer (score 6):

it's much more easy to check for your first loop-iteration, wrte the comma before your text and leave this comma aout on the first iteration:

```
<?php
if ($articles) { 
    $firstiteration = true:
    foreach($articles as $article) { 
        if(!$firstiteration){
            echo ", ";
        }
        $firstiteration = false;
        echo $article->name;       
    } // end foreach article
} // end if has articles
?>
```

another (more beautiful in my optionion) possibility would be to override the _toSting()-method of your article-class:

```
...
function __toString(){
    return $this->name;
}
...
```

and simply `echo implode(", ",$articles)`

Comment: +1 One small error in your first code snippet though, `echo $article->name.", ";` should be `echo $article->name;`...

Comment: other small error - setting firstIteration to false should happen OUTSIDE of the if block, or it will never run

Comment: Rather than checking for the first iteration, this is an **excellent** place to break out the old general `for` loop. Those do exist you know :)

Comment: @Billy that only works if its a numerically indexed array.  you intend to do the first 'manually' and then iterate for the remaining elements?

Answer (score 3):

It is better way to do what you want:

```
<?php
$string = '';
if ($articles) { 
    foreach($articles as $article) { 
        $string .= $article->name.", ";       
    }
}
$string = substr($string, 0, -2);
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: better or not better but quite nice one

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a lot of good array functions, and this screams for one of them.

```
$namesArray = array_map(function($x){return $x->name;}, $articles);
$string = implode(',' $namesArray);
```

OR

```
$first = true;
array_walk(function($x) use (&$first)
           {
               if(!$first) {echo ', ';} else{$first = false;}
               echo $x->name;
           }, $articles);
```

I really like the above response with the __toString function also, but I wanted to show these array functions because i think they are often underused in favor or unnecessary foreach loops.

Comment: +1 for showing array_map - i would prefer the toString/implode-combination or a foreach-loop in this case, but everybody should know these array-function (and a lot of people do not)

Comment: @oezi array_map works with arrays. as well as implode, which was the OP's problem.

Comment: @oezi i dont see your +1   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove last comma and space by using trim function. It is the easiest way..

```
<?php
    if ($articles) { 
         foreach($articles as $article) { 
             echo trim(implode(", ", $article->name), ', '); 
         }
     }
?>
```